# Video on SmartEyeGlass

Tags: sony-smarteyeglass

Is it possible to play a simple and short video on smart eye glasses?
I know that it can play audio and it can show images one after the other. It should not be too much work from there I am just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct support for video playback, but as Ahmet says, you can approach this with showing Bitmaps as fast as possible.

The playback speed depends on the connection - so it is recommended to use High performance mode - wifi connection to achieve highest frame rate ([setPowerMode](https://developer.sony.com/reference/seg-sdk/com/sony/smarteyeglass/extension/util/SmartEyeglassControlUtils#setPowerMode%28int%29))

Also take a look at [showBitmapWithCallback](https://developer.sony.com/reference/seg-sdk/com/sony/smarteyeglass/extension/util/SmartEyeglassControlUtils#showBitmapWithCallback%28Bitmap,%20int%29) which provides you a callback right after previous frame gets rendered, so you can show another one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can grab frames of the video and display them one after another, as bitmaps.

That should give you a video playback view on the SmartEyeglass.